# How to check if given timestamp is 10 minutes old?

Tags: php

I have a timestamp in '2013-04-10T09:00:00Z' format and based on this I want to check the requested datetime format is within 10 minutes or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that I tried and it worked for me,

```
$currentDateTime =new DateTime();
$currentDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$userDateTime = new DateTime($timestamp); //convert users incoming   

$diff = $now->diff($then);

$minutes = ($diff->format('%a')*1440)+($diff->format('%h')*60)+ ($diff->format('%i')); 

if($minutes <=10)
{
     //your code goes here
}
else
{
   //time difference is more then 10 minutes<br/>
}
```

Thanks Francisco for all your post.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$now       = time();
$timestamp = strtotime('2013/04/08T09:00:00Z');
$timediff  = $now - $timestamp;

if (floor($timediff/60) > 10) {
    echo 'Time is 10 minutes older';
}
else {
    echo 'Time is not older then 10 min';
}
```

Comment: Seems `$datediff` in condition should be `$timediff`, or other ways.

Comment: its always gives me message 'Time is not older then 10 min' even if my time is not older. Is this a problem with timezone. I edited my $timestamp=strtotime('2013/04/08T11:30:00Z'); and my current time is 11:32:00.

Comment: Yes, I think you may have a conflict of timezone, I tried the same timestamp and it is getting 12:30 for me... You should set the default timezone with http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Below is the code that I tried and it worked for me, 

   $currentDateTime =new DateTime();
   
    $currentDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
   
    $userDateTime = new DateTime($timestamp); //convert users   incoming   //request time to datetime

    $diff = $now->diff($then);

    $minutes = ($diff->format('%a')*1440) + ($diff->format('%h')*60)+   ($diff->format('%i')); 

    if($minutes <=10)
{
//your code goes here
}
else
{
   //time difference is more then 10 minutes<br/>
}

Thanks Francisco for all your post.